# How to transform a list to an array in kotlin

Tags: arrays, list, kotlin

I have a list

```
val rewardList: List<Reward>
class Reward(
    val nameBefore: String     
    val amountBefore: Long
)
```

I want to have

```
val rewardArray: Array<TransReward>
class TransReward(
    val nameAfter: String     
    val amountAfter: Long
)
```

There is `name mapping` involved and I can't figure out a good way to change `list` to `array`.

P.S. The class design is previous code in the system so I can't change it.

Comment: *What* is the "name mapping" involved?

Comment: Just simply map value of `nameBefore` to `nameAfter` and map value of `amountBefore` to `amountAfter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To transform `List` to `Array` you could use `.toTypedArray()`,but in your case you can't transform `List<Reward>` to  `Array<TransReward>` because the class type are different.

My solution is to transform your `Reward` to `TransReward` first and then use `.toTypedArray()`

```kotlin
val rewardList: List<Reward>
class Reward(
    val nameBefore: String     
    val amountBefore: Long
){
  fun toTransReward(): TransReward = TransReward(
     nameAfter = this.nameBefore,
     amountAfter = this.amountBefore
  )
}

// use it like this
val rewardArray : Array<TransReward> = rewardList.map{ it.toTransReward() }.toTypedArray()
```

Comment: I suggest using the name "toTransReward" to follow convention. "as" implies a cast or a wrapper class.

Comment: @Tenfour04 i was thinking that it is a casting since it does nothing but cast the value from class A to B , that's why i am using "as" as the function name , but idk, it's probably my misunderstanding about "casting".

Comment: This is not casting. "cast" has a very specific definition in Kotlin. It is done using the `as` keyword and it doesn't do any conversion. It is only an assertion that an instance of something is *already* an instance of the type you are casting to.

Comment: I think you are right and i also agree with you that it is only an assertion , thanks for the explanation, i'll edit my answer